# Calculating the overall mean, not a mean of means

Tags: r, mean

I feel like this is a *really* simple question which I should be able to figure out but I have been trying for a while now to no success. I have a dataframe and wish to determine the overall mean rt by cond type and by speaker type, ignoring position. How do I do this?

Simply, three groups of people read sentences ("Speaker"). Each "cond" is a different sentence type ("ExpA, B, C, D), all made of 5 parts ("Position"). Each part has a corresponding reading time in each sentence type. I want to look at the overall reading time for each cond (all positions together) for each group. Eg. the sum of all position reading times (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) for just FR participants for cond "ExpA" to compare whether they were faster or slower overall in "ExpA" than "ExpB".

```
Dataframe: 
Speaker: FR, EN, KR
cond (ExpA, ExpB, ExpC, ExpD)
Position (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
rt: 1000, 1500, 2000, 1500, 1000
```

How would I do this? I've been able to get the mean rt by position, condition, and speaker using the code below, but when I remove "position" thinking it will then give me the combined mean for each "cond", it gives me only one value which is too small to be the sum of 5 means, rather it looks to be a mean of those means.

```
pcsmeans = ddply(subj.means, .(cond, position, speaker), summarise, sd = sd(mean.rt), mean = mean(mean.rt))
```

I hope the lack of proper dataframe isn't offputting, I don't know how to input one of those here. Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly unclear what you are after but looks like you could use `dplyr`'s `group_by` and `summarise`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(Speaker =  rep(c("FR", "EN", "KR"),20),
       cond =  rep(c("ExpA", "ExpB", "ExpC", "ExpD"),15),
       Position = rep(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4),12),
       rt = runif(min=1000, max=2000, n = 60))

df %>% group_by(Speaker, cond) %>% summarise(mean_rt = mean(rt), overall_rt = sum(rt))
```

This gives you the mean and sum by Speaker and cond:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   Speaker [3]
Speaker cond  mean_rt overall_rt
<fct>   <fct>   <dbl>      <dbl>
1 EN      ExpA    1690.      8449.
2 EN      ExpB    1625.      8127.
3 EN      ExpC    1588.      7940.
4 EN      ExpD    1475.      7375.
5 FR      ExpA    1321.      6603.
6 FR      ExpB    1584.      7922.
7 FR      ExpC    1493.      7465.
8 FR      ExpD    1463.      7315.
9 KR      ExpA    1393.      6965.
10 KR      ExpB    1540.      7702.
11 KR      ExpC    1569.      7847.
12 KR      ExpD    1570.      7849.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!
What I'm looking for is close to what you've responded. It definitely isolates it by cond, which I was looking for, but also seems to still be a mean of means.

 ` cond  mean_rt overall_rt
  <fct>   <dbl>      <dbl>
1 ExpA    1061.     295007
2 ExpB    1064.     292615
3 ExpC    1096.     304693
4 ExpD    1111.     297681`

I'm after the combined means of all positions 0-4 per cond per Speaker group. So the (mean of all values for pos0 for ExpA) plus (the mean of all values for pos1 for ExpA) plus (mean of all values for pos2 for ExpA) etc. If that helps?

Comment: So this?   
`df %>% group_by(Speaker, cond, Position) %>% summarise(mean_rt = mean(rt)) %>% group_by(Speaker, cond) %>% summarise(sum_mean_rt = sum(mean_rt))`

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what your actual issue is. Since you already mentioned that you do not know ho to add a sample data.frame, here is one example which I guess fits your problem:

```
#generate mock df
speaker<-c("FR", "EN", "KR")
exp<-c("ExpA", "ExpB", "ExpC", "ExpD")
position<-c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
#rt<- 1000, 1500, 2000, 1500, 1000
data<-expand.grid(speaker,exp,position)
names(data)<-c('speaker','exp','position')
data$rt<-rnorm(n=nrow(data),mean = 1300,sd = 250)
head(data)

speaker  exp    position  rt
FR       ExpA   0         1269
EN       ExpA   0         859
KR       ExpA   0         863
FR       ExpB   0         718
EN       ExpB   0         956
KR       ExpB   0         867
...
```

From this point on, there's multiple options. My preferred quick & efficient tool comes with the sqldf package, which introduces sql language like constructs. SQL is super efficient and easy to read:

```
require(sqldf)
sqldf::sqldf('select count(*) as N, speaker, exp, avg(rt) as mean from df group by speaker, exp')
```

Obviously, R has a million tools when it comes to solving a problem, but this is my favourite by far. For anything more complex (i.e. custom functions etc.), I'd probably use a for loop that iterates through each reader and exp combination:

```
data$identifier <- paste0(data$speaker,data$exp) # helper column
results <- data.frame()
for ( ident in unique(data$identifier) ){
  df <- subset(data, identifier == ident)
  speaker<-unique(df$speaker)
  exp<-unique(df$exp)
  
  mean<-sum( df$rt )  
  se<-sd( df$rt )/ sqrt( nrow(df) )
  quantileButTransformed <- t(as.data.frame(quantile(df$rt))) #whatever you can think of
  
  newLine<-data.frame(speaker = speaker, exp = exp,N = nrow(df), mean = mean, se = se, quantile = quantileButTransformed)
  results <- rbind(results, newLine)
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: That's a lot of information! Thank you for showing me how to add the sample data frame!

What I'm trying to find is the mean total sentence reading times per condition per speaker. How long each sentence took each group to read overall (as a sum of the mean rts for pos0-4 in each sentence.

Mean rt ExpA FR speakers = 5000ms (sum of mean rts pos0-4)